# Necesito ayuda en para escribir una linea de codigo en Mysql

Tags: mysql, select

Soy nuevo en mysql, llevo todo el día tratando de realizar lo siguiente:

**¿Como sería el código que muestre la cantidad de estudiantes que hay  inscritos en cada uno de los tutoriales?**

Tabla Inscritos

```
mysql> select * from Inscritos;
+----+--------------+------------+
| id | estudianteId | tutorialId |
+----+--------------+------------+
|  1 |            1 |          1 |
|  2 |            1 |          2 |
|  3 |            3 |          1 |
|  4 |            5 |          2 |
|  5 |            5 |          3 |
|  6 |            7 |          1 |
|  7 |            7 |          2 |
|  8 |            7 |          3 |
+----+--------------+------------+
```

Tabla estudiantes:

```
mysql> select * from Student;
+----+-----------+----------+   
| id | firstname | lastname |
+----+-----------+----------+
|  1 | John      | Doe      |
|  2 | Mary      | Moe      |
|  3 | Julie     | Dooley   |
|  4 | Johanna   | Robatti  |
|  5 | Ham       | Ludwing  |
|  6 | Bruce     | Heckel   |
|  7 | Robert    | Sanekis  |
|  8 | Irving    | Utianov  |
|  9 | Mark      | Spencer  |
| 10 | Daysi     | Oconnor  |
+----+-----------+----------+
```

Tabla tutoriales:

```
mysql> select * from tutorials;
+----+---------------+-----------+------------+
| id | title         | author    | date       |
+----+---------------+-----------+------------+
|  1 | Learn Python  | John Paul | 2018-06-06 |
|  2 | Learn MySQL   | Abdul S   | 2018-06-06 |
|  3 | JAVA Tutorial | Sanjay    | 2017-11-05 |
+----+---------------+-----------+------------+
```

Creación de la tabla Inscritos:

```
mysql> create table Inscritos(
-> id int(6) not null auto_increment,
-> estudianteId int(6) unsigned not null,
-> tutorialId int(6) not null,
-> primary key(id),
-> index (estudianteId),
-> index (tutorialId),
-> foreign key(estudianteId) references Student(id),
-> foreign key(tutorialId) references Tutorials(id)
-> );
```

Como pueden ver las tablas Student y Tutorials son FK de la tabla Inscritos.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: @x-rw creo que la pregunta es esta: Muestra la cantidad de estudiantes inscritos tienen cada uno de los tutoriales.

Comment: la redaccion esta mal, no podemos adivinar su pregunta, deberia mejorar su redaccion para que obtenga respuestas de calidad

Comment: tienes razón por eso no le he respondido nada por que no lo entiendo

Comment: tampoco se entiende el titulo, a que linea de codigo se refiere?

Comment: @AlfredoPaz he mejorado la redacción.

Comment: Y que intentaste hasta el momento?

Comment: Creo que lo que pides es el Query que te de la cantidad de incisritos por cada tutorial, esto lo puedes hacer agrupando por tutorialId y haciendo un count

Comment: Esto deberia intentarlo ya que claramente es una tarea para lo que este estudiando, y despues si se traba lo podemos ayudar

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podriamos hacer el trabajo por ti, pero de esa forma nos estarian calificando a nosotros. Tomate el trabajo de intentar hacer algo, y venir cuando te trabes en una parte en especifico.

Comment: @gbianchi Hasta el momento llevo esto: `mysql> select title,count(*) from tutorials,Inscritos,student where student.id in(select estudianteId from Inscritos,student where estudianteId = student.id) group by title;`

Comment: Usa el boton [edit] y agrega en la pregunta lo que intentaste hasta ahora

Comment: @gbianchi he intentado hacer una subconsulta, pero no se como formularla

Comment: A que te referis que no sabes como formularla? ese query ya tiene una subconsulta, lo que pasa es que esta haciendo un full join de las tres tablas. y esa informacion debe estar si o si dentro del cuerpo de la pregunta no en comentarios.

Comment: Puedes generar la consulta desde PHPMyAdmin y se te hara mucho mas facil.
Lo descargas desde [este enlace](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/)
Y luego lo copias a tu carpeta localhost (esto varia si usas Apache, Xampp, Mampp, IIS) pero la idea es que lo ejecutes en tu servidor local y desde esa aplicacion (PHPMyAdmin) manejes tus bases de datos y puedas realizar las consultas que requieras, modificar las tablas, exportar/importar un archivo .sql, etc... Puedes ver el siguiente [video en youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vS8DA29WsVw) que explica paso a paso como generar una consulta u

Comment: Creo que es esto lo que buscas:  `select title, ifnull(count(*),0) from tutorials t left join Inscritos i on i.tutorialId = t.id group by title;`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Seria algo como :

```
Select turorialid,Count(estudianteId)
from Inscritos
```

No se como de bien estará ,mi sql esta un poco oxidados,no Obstante te recomiento que hagas estos tutoriales,te enselan a realizar consultas y te las corrigen: http://sqlzoo.net/